# proc_open syntax error unexpected [

Tags: php, proc-open

Hello I get this error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in 
/home/zh004600/www_root/public/text/qr.php on line 24
```

line 24 is:

```
$x = proc_open("/www_root/public/text '--format=raw' '--lzma1=lc=3,lp=0,pb=2,dict=128KiB' '-c' '-'", 
[0 => ["pipe", "r"], 1 => ["pipe", "w"]], $p);
```

what is wrong?
Thanks

Comment: What version of PHP are you using? <5.4 by any chance?

Comment: ^^^ Yes definitely.

Comment: ok, I change from 5.3 to 5.5, now problem with mysql_connect() I need to use mysqli but code is working, thanx